# PowerShell: Remove Trailing "..."

Tags: string, powershell

I'm trying to create a powershell script that will get the list of scheduled tasks. I've got far enough to get a complete list of tasks, however I need to remove the trailing "..."

How do you do that?

```
$tasks | Select-String -pattern "Disabled" | ft @{Expression
={$_.Line};Label="Line";width=44}
```

Output:

```
Line
----
AD RMS Rights Policy Template Management ...
AD RMS Rights Policy Template Management ...
Proxy                                    ...
UserTask                                 ...
UserTask-Roam                            ...
Consolidator                             ...
KernelCeipTask                           ...
UsbCeip                                  ...
ScheduledDefrag                          ...
Scheduled                                ...
Microsoft-Windows-DiskDiagnosticDataColl ...
Microsoft-Windows-DiskDiagnosticResolver ...
Notifications                            ...
WinSAT                                   ...
ActivateWindowsSearch                    ...
ConfigureInternetTimeService             ...
DispatchRecoveryTasks                    ...
ehDRMInit                                ...
InstallPlayReady                         ...
mcupdate                                 ...
MediaCenterRecoveryTask                  ...
ObjectStoreRecoveryTask                  ...
OCURActivate                             ...
OCURDiscovery                            ...
PBDADiscovery                            ...
PBDADiscoveryW1                          ...
PBDADiscoveryW2                          ...
PeriodicScanRetry                        ...
PvrRecoveryTask                          ...
PvrScheduleTask                          ...
RecordingRestart                         ...
RegisterSearch                           ...
ReindexSearchRoot                        ...
SqlLiteRecoveryTask                      ...
UpdateRecordPath                         ...
CorruptionDetector                       ...
DecompressionFailureDetector             ...
HotStart                                 ...
LPRemove                                 ...
SystemSoundsService                      ...
GatherNetworkInfo                        ...
Background Synchronization               ...
Logon Synchronization                    ...
AnalyzeSystem                            ...
RacTask                                  ...
RegIdleBackup                            ...
WindowsParentalControls                  ...
WindowsParentalControlsMigration         ...
AutoWake                                 ...
GadgetManager                            ...
SessionAgent                             ...
SystemDataProviders                      ...
SR                                       ...
Interactive                              ...
IpAddressConflict1                       ...
IpAddressConflict2                       ...
MsCtfMonitor                             ...
SynchronizeTime                          ...
ResolutionHost                           ...
QueueReporting                           ...
BfeOnServiceStartTypeChange              ...
UpdateLibrary                            ...
ConfigNotification                       ...
Calibration Loader                       ...
```

Comment: This is answer: but cannot submit it; $tasks | Select-String -pattern "Disabled" | ForEach-Object
{ $_ -replace "Disabled", ""} | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "Could not start",
""} | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Format-Table (ft) since it will attempt to fit the data within the number of columns available in the console and you've limited the space for the "line" column to 44 chars.  Try this instead:

```
$tasks | Select-String -pattern "Disabled" | Foreach {$_.Line}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$tasks | Select-String -pattern "Disabled" | ForEach-Object
{ $_ -replace "Disabled", ""} | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "Could not start",
""} | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }
```

Does exactly as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what $tasks has in it so I wrote this based off get-service but it should work in your case:

```
$tasks | Select-String -pattern "Disabled" | ft @{Expression=
{$intLength = 44; if($_.Line.length -lt $intLength) {$intLength=$_.Line.length} $_.Line.substring(0,$intLength)};Label="Line"}
```